# selecting a new row daily in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database in which there is table **Counselor**
Now I want to loop through the records one by one each day.
That means selecting one record today,next record tomorrow and so on until all the records are selected and then again same procedure start.
There can be any no. of records in database. How can I do it ?
I am using **php**.

Comment: give an example ! I cannot under stand your problem

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting a record for any particular date? What do you want to do with that selected record?

Answer (score 1):

**Cron Job**

You can go fro Cron Job for this kind of stuff. Create a php file which has the code to get the datas from DB for the current particular day. Then run that Cron Job Daily at a particular time. (i.e) set the time daily for that cron job to run. So it will run automatically and get the daily record.